# Format an array of PHP objects in twig

Tags: php, arrays, twig

I have an array of objects of a php class which has three variables x y and z:

Following is a representation to clarify how the data is. 1st column belong to variable x, 2nd column belong to variable y and 3rd column belong to variable z

```
A 1 $

A 2 #

A 3 @

B 2 &

B 7 *

C 8 !
```

I want to display this data in a formatted way in HTML as follows using **TWIG**. I'm looking forward for a technique in twig to render it in the way I want.

```
A
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>$</td>
    </tr>
    <br>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>#</td>
    </tr>
    <br>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>@</td>
    </tr>
</table>


B
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>&</td>
    </tr>
    <br>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>*</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I can access the variables of the object likewise : `{% result[0].getVarX() %}` will return A.

PS. I tried to boil down to the core problem here. I'm using an MVC along with TWIG and I get that data from the database. So Instead of pasting 100's of lines of code, I tried to ask the actual question.

Thank You

Comment: I wouldn't recommend Twig as the way to do this as you would have to rebuild the result set to be organized by the `x` variable that you mention. This type of rebuilding in Twig is rather roundabout as you have to repeatedly `merge` lists together with a `for` loop. You should manipulate the data in your controller before passing it to Twig.

Comment: The current solution that I have uses a `foreach` implementation and compares the current and the previous variable x which I confess is a dirty workaround solution but still there is a small problem.

Comment: I'm open to a solution where I can manipulate the data in the controller before passing it to Twig. However, I'm not sure how I can achieve that. Actually, I have a lot of variables in the object I am dealing with. For simplicity purpose I dubbed them with just 3 variables.